# Cloning Table Schema In AWS Via Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm working with an existing Rails application (hosted on PostgreSQL on Heroku), and looking to add a new database in AWS that will be the clone of an external database and will be updated every 2 hours with new data from the original table.

Is there a simple Rails script I can use to copy the schema and existing data from the original database into the new AWS instance?